# How to get dynamic height from mounted element in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3

How can I calculate the dynamic height of the menu in pixels using VueJS?

Below using a method, I am attempting to target the first child `li` element of `ref="menu"`, following the mounting of the component. My result is `null`.

```
<template>
    ....
    <ul ref="menu">
        <li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            {{ item }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    ....
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        method:{
            doSomething(){
                console.log(
                    this.$refs.days.querySelector('li:first-of-type').offsetHeight
                )
            }
        }
        mounted(){
            this.doSomething()
        }
    }
</script?
```

---

I was able to resolve part of the issue using an on-load event listener.

```
mounted(){
    window.addEventListener('load', this.doSomething)
},
beforeUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('load', this.doSomething)
}
```

However, `this.doSomething` does not run when returning to the page via route. I've attempted using the following hooks: beforeRouteEnter, beforeRouteUpdate, beforeRouteLeave; though none are fired from the destination page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use nexttick function from vuejs.

```
mounted() {
 

  this.$nextTick(() => {
      //here the DOM is updated
      this.doSomething();
  });
```

}

More info about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: `$nextTick` fires when navigating away from a route. I would need something firing on the route being navigated into. I've since capitulated and hard-coded the element height. Bright side, I was then able to remove the onload event listeners altogether, cleaning up the code.